# How to sort a LatLng pointList in leaflet

Tags: javascript, sorting, leaflet, polyline

I have a pointList like the following

```
var pointList=[
new L.LatLng(lat1,lon1),
new L.LatLng(lat2,lon2),
new L.LatLng(lat3,lon3),
new L.LatLng(lat4,lon4),
new L.LatLng(lat5,lon5),
new L.LatLng(lat6,lon6),
new L.LatLng(lat7,lon7)
];
```

I want to draw a polyLine using these points. I am using the following code to draw the polyLine

```
L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: color,
    weight: 10,
    lineCap:"square",
    lineJoin:"bevel",
    opacity: 0.6,
    smoothFactor: 1
    });
```

But I am seeing multiple polyLines diverging from one point to another. That looks just weird. See the following image. 
[image: polylines]

I guess if I could sort the points then I could get only one line instead of multiple lines. Can you give me any idea how to sort these points? Or is there any easy way to draw a polyline instead multiple diverging lines?

I am attaching a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyztr17y/1/) to give you an ide what i want to do. Remove the first entry from the pointlist and move it to the bottom. The line then looks progressing gradually. My goal is exactly like that.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pyztr17y/1/  Hello please see this. Move the first [lat, lon] pair to bottom then the line looks exactly what i want. That means the points are sorted. How can i make a list of such points sorted in code?

Comment: Hey, I am having exact same problem. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Polyline is constructed between the points you pass and in the order you pass them.

From the image you posted I guess you are trying to visualize a trace of some object like a car. You should have some sort of timestamp or incremental identifier that you can use to order the points.

Otherwise you can write a simple algorithm that starts from the first point and calculates the distances to all the others and picks the closest one and you add it as the second point and so on.